# How to execute an IF statement then continue to other code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a piece of code that needs to check if the user registration is from admin page or not. If it does, it will change the user role admin to true then continue to the code below it, and if it doesn't came from admin page then the code inside the if statement will not run but the code below it will run.

```
 if (userData.admin === true) {
     users.findOneAndUpdate({ username: userData.username }, { $set: { admin: true } }, { new: true })
          .exec(function (err) {
             if (err) throw err;
          });
 }

console.log('This should execute');
```

I am using this approach but when the user sign up from an admin page, the console log is not running. How can I do this?

Comment: Perhaps it's throwing `err`.

Comment: what ever the case your console.log('This should execute'); should run because findOneAndUpdate is async and that console.log('This should execute'); should run what ever the if condition is

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are missing a callback on that async "findOneAndUpdate". Since you only handle the "err" and not the respons from the "findOneAndUpdate" the code will not escape out from the initial if statement. and so the console.log will not run because the browser is waiting for a callback. just add an callback to the "findOneAndUpdate" and put it after the "err" if statement and the console.log should run.

```
if (userData.admin === true) {
     users.findOneAndUpdate({ username: userData.username }, { $set: { admin: true } }, { new: true }, callback(err, res))
          if (err){ throw err;};
          res(true);
 }

console.log('This should execute');
```

Note the callback in the "findOneAndUpdate" function, and the "res(true)" after the err handler.

Hope this helps